# Using `unwrap` to remove immediate parent in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

I have a html structure using which user can create a navigation or menu for html templates.The user can drag drop and create menus and sub menus.When he clicks update,the menu gets updated with whatever changes are made.This is built dynamically and the html ceated is as below

```
<ol class="sortable ui-sortable" id="addMenu">
 <li>
  <div class="droppable ui-droppable">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);">Menu1</a>
  </div>
  <ol>
   <li style="display: list-item;">
     <div class="droppable ui-droppable">
       <a href="javascript:void(0);">Menu2</a>
     </div>
   </li>
  </ol>
 </li>
 <li>
    <div class="droppable ui-droppable">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">Menu3</a>
    </div>
 </li>
```

What we want to achieve is,when the user says create a menu or updates it,the `div` with `class=droppable` should be removed from every where in the structure,with rest of the structure intact.

I tried it using the `.unwrap()` and `replaceWith()` functions but doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
var menuHtml = $('#addMenu').html();
menuHtml = '<ol id="toRmv">'+menuHtml+'</ol>';

$('#'+IdParent+' .navigationInner').html(menuHtml);
var newHtml = $('#'+IdParent+' .navigationInner').html();

$menuHtml = $("#toRmv div.droppable > a").unwrap();

$('#'+IdParent+' .navigationInner').html($menuHtml);
```

How can achieve it?

Comment: What does `$(this)` refer to there?

Comment: `$(this)` is the html content I have mentioned above.

Comment: The `ol`? The `li`? The `div`? You need to show us more context.

Comment: @Eric I have updated the question.The context mentioned is the one that I use.We are trying to build a navigation using this structure.

Comment: @Eric Thank you eric for the inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the droppable `div` from around the anchor, then:

```
$("#addMenu div.droppable > a").unwrap();
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uzofih/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/uzofih/1/edit)

Comment: I have updated the question with your solution added,but in my context it un wraps all the parents except the anchor tag.This is what we get. `<a class="submenu" href="javascript:void(0);">Menu1</a><a class="submenu" href="javascript:void(0);">Menu2</a><a class="submenu" href="javascript:void(0);">Menu3</a>`